# Three way transaction

Tags: ios

I am building an iPhone App that will have a buyer, a seller and the App (platform).  I need to collect from buyer and transfer funds (minus any fees) to seller.  Can I built this in using PayPal?  I want to minimize collecting seller info to provide sensitive info such as ssn, dob, etc.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [PayPal iOS SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK) and see if it fits your need.